# how to enable formcontrol based on check box selection

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have a formcontrol as shown below which is read-only and i want to make it editable based on check box selection

```
 <input matInput id="Proposedtude" formControlName="Proposedtude" placeholder="Enter Proposed tude" type="text" readonly="true" required />
```

In typescript file i did following code on check box selection but did not worked

```
 site: FormGroup;
if(event.target.checked) {

this.site.controls['Proposedtude'].enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `enable()` or `disable()` methods on your formControl. The methods are inherited from [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable).

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbrmek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this.site.controls['Proposedtude'].disable();
                this.site.controls['Proposedtude'].disable();  not working

Comment: I've created a stackblitz example, and updated the answer.